"ERROR: Cursor does not exist" in PL/pgSQL procedure
I am trying to transfer a specific amount of film with an specific quantity from one store_id to another. For this I have tried doing a procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE transfer_inventory(
    p_film_id INTEGER,
    p_from_store_id INTEGER,
    p_to_store_id INTEGER,
    p_quantity INTEGER
) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    v_inventory_id INTEGER;
    v_current_quantity INTEGER;
    v_transferred_quantity INTEGER := 0;
    v_remaining_quantity INTEGER;
    v_total_available_quantity INTEGER := 0;
    v_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT inventory_id, COUNT(*) AS film_count
        FROM inventory
        WHERE film_id = p_film_id AND store_id = p_from_store_id
        GROUP BY inventory_id;
BEGIN
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(film_count), 0) INTO v_total_available_quantity
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS film_count
        FROM inventory
        WHERE film_id = p_film_id AND store_id = p_from_store_id
        GROUP BY inventory_id
    ) AS temp;

    RAISE NOTICE 'Se desean transferir % unidades de la película %.', p_quantity, p_film_id;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Hay % unidades disponibles para transferir.', v_total_available_quantity;

    IF v_total_available_quantity < p_quantity THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'No hay suficientes películas para completar la transferencia.';
        RETURN;
    END IF;

    -- Open cursors
    OPEN v_cursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH NEXT FROM v_cursor INTO v_inventory_id, v_current_quantity;

        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

        v_remaining_quantity := p_quantity - v_transferred_quantity;

        IF v_current_quantity >= v_remaining_quantity THEN
                            
            RAISE NOTICE 'Transferencia de % unidades de la película % a la tienda %.', v_remaining_quantity, p_film_id, p_to_store_id;
            
            EXIT WHEN v_transferred_quantity = p_quantity;
        ELSE
            -- No enough units to transfer
            RAISE NOTICE 'No hay suficientes películas para completar la transferencia.';
            ROLLBACK;
            EXIT;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    -- Cursor closure
    CLOSE v_cursor;

    -- Verify if all units where transfered
    IF v_transferred_quantity < p_quantity THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'No se pudo transferir la cantidad solicitada de películas.';
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'Se han transferido % unidades de la película %.', v_transferred_quantity, p_film_id;
    END IF;
END;
$$;

But I get the following error:

SQL Error [34000]:
ERROR: Cursor "<unnamed portal 9>" does not exist
Where: PL/pgSQL function transfer_inventory(integer,integer,integer,integer) on line 72 in CLOSE


Apparently, it's a closure issue of my cursor, but it is being closed after de loop ends.
I am new to plpgsql so my solutions are limited.

Answer to immediate problem
The immediate cause for the error message is that cursors only live for the duration of a transaction. You close the transaction with ROLLBACK (which immediately starts a new transaction in a PROCEDURE). So the cursor is already gone when you reach CLOSE v_cursor;. Bang, exception!
The manual:

All portals are implicitly closed at transaction end. Therefore a
refcursor value is usable to reference an open cursor only until the
end of the transaction.

Removing ROLLBACK would remove the error. But that's just putting lipstick on a pig.
A cursor is rarely the best choice in PL/pgSQL
Typically, a FOR loop (with implicit cursor) is simpler, faster and less error prone. See:

Postgres FOR LOOP

Your task is not entirely clear. You lead with:

transfer a specific amount of film with an specific quantity from one store_id to another.

But then no transfer happens in the code. Other basic info is missing, too.  So I won't try to translate your procedure. Also, I suspect all you need is a simple SQL query.
Plain SQL
Going out on a limb, your task probably burns down to something like this UPDATE command (with attached CTE):
WITH sel AS (   
   SELECT inventory_id
   FROM   inventory
   WHERE  film_id = p_film_id
   AND    store_id = p_from_store_id
   ORDER  BY inventory_id
   FETCH  FIRST p_quantity ROWS WITH TIES
   FOR    UPDATE  -- optional - if there can be concurrent, competing writes
   )
UPDATE inventory i
SET    film_id = p_to_store_id
FROM   sel s
WHERE  s.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
AND    i.film_id = p_film_id;

Assuming you want to transfer all rows of the same inventory_id, and at least p_quantity in total.
See:

Get top row(s) with highest value, with ties
Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1


I'll refine and explain some more if you clarify your objective and provide required details in the question (and ping me in a comment).
